# Filtering React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, filtering

I need help with simple filtering todo list I've managed to get removing and adding tasks to works good but now I'm trying to filter through added tasks and I get the error message I'm completely beginner so please keep that in mind Thanks!

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

> 26 |     this.setState({query: evt.target.value});

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import  Form from './Form';
import  List from './List';

class App extends Component {

state = {
    query: '',
    inputValue: "",
    todos: [
        {value: 'Naumiej  się Reacta', done: false},
        {value: 'Pucuj trzewiki ', done: true},
    ]
}
handleChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({inputValue: evt.target.value});
}
removeMe = (index) =>{
    this.setState({
        todos: this.state.todos.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
    })
}

searchChanged(evt) {
    this.setState({query: evt.target.value});
}

handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const newTodo = {
        value: this.state.inputValue
    };
    const todos = this.state.todos;
    todos.push(newTodo);
    this.setState({todos: todos, inputValue: ''})

}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." onChange=
{this.searchChanged} />
            <Form
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
                handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}

            />
            <List
                removeMe={this.removeMe}
                todos={this.state.todos}
                query={this.state.query}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

List

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import  Task from './Task';
class List extends Component {

render() {
    let serchedTasks = this.props.todos.filter(
        (todos) => {
            return todos.value.indexOf(this.props.query) !== -1;
        }
    );
    return (
        <div className="List">
            {serchedTasks.map((todo, index) => {
                return (
                    <Task
                        key={index}
                        index={index}
                        removeMe={this.props.removeMe}
                        todo={todo}
                    />
                )
            })}

        </div>
    )
}
}
export default List;
```

Comment: Change `searchChanged` to an arrow function, or bind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`searchChanged(evt)` isn't bound to `this`.

Redefine it as an arrow function.

```
searchChanged = (evt) => {
  this.setState({query: evt.target.value})
}
```

Comment: Thank You !!!  You made my day!

Comment: proszę bardzo ahah

Answer (score 0):

Use an arrow function like you did with the others :

`searchChanged = (evt) => {`